# ¿Existe alguna forma de saber si una función recibe argumentos en PHP?

Tags: php

Es decir si tengo la siguiente función:

```
public function miFuncion($param1) {
       
       // Mi código 
}
```

¿Cómo podría saber si tengo que pasarle los argumentos para los parámetros establecidos?

Comment: Hola, no entiendo bien la última parte que escribiste, ¿podrías explicarla mejor?

Comment: No entiendo... cuando llames la función, si no le pasas los parámetros, arrojará un error...

Comment: Exacto arroja error, por eso la pregunta de si hay alguna forma de saber si esa función necesita argumentos antes de llamarla para validar y que no muestre el error.

Comment: @SrQuike esto no es posible, tu pregunta es ilógica debido a que una función a la que le pasas parámetros insuficientes arrojará inevitablemente un error, en este caso, PHP te dará un error HTTP 500, si está en tu mismo archivo, el IDE en que trabajas te puede ir diciendo que parámetros y tipos de datos necesitas.

Comment: De hecho @anythingg checa tanto el comentario de ordago y la respuesta de AlfaBravo

Comment: Si es ilógico, pero para la implementación que estoy realizando (personal) tenia curiosidad de saber si era posible hacerlo. Y la respuesta de @Alfabravo me sirvió.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tendrías que usar reflection para inspeccionar cómo está implementado el método.

Algo como [este método ReflectionFunction::getParameters](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getparameters.php). Cito uno de los comentarios de usuarios en esa documentación (incompleta) oficial

```
<?php

$valuesToProcess = [
  'name' => 'Anderson Lucas Silva de Oliveira',
  'age' => 21,
  'hobbie' => 'Play games'
];

function processUserData($name, $age, $job = "", $hobbie = "")
{
    $msg = "Hello $name. You have $age years old";
    if (!empty($job)) {
    $msg .= ". Your job is $job";
    }

    if (!empty($hobbie)) {
        $msg .= ". Your hobbie is $hobbie";
    }

    echo $msg . ".";
}

$refFunction = new ReflectionFunction('processUserData');
$parameters = $refFunction->getParameters();

$validParameters = [];
foreach ($parameters as $parameter) {
    if (!array_key_exists($parameter->getName(), $valuesToProcess) && !$parameter->isOptional()) {
        throw new DomainException('Cannot resolve the parameter' . $parameter->getName());
    }

    if(!array_key_exists($parameter->getName(), $valuesToProcess)) {
        continue;
    }

    $validParameters[$parameter->getName()] = $valuesToProcess[$parameter->getName()];
}

$refFunction->invoke(...$validParameters);
?>
```

Que tendría como salida

> Hello Anderson Lucas Silva de Oliveira. You have 21 years old. Your hobbie is Play games.

Comment: Cierto lo de que esta incpmpleta :), mas aún con un *Warning
This function is currently not documented; only its argument list is available.* pero algún día algún día

Comment: Perfecto es justo lo que buscaba, gracias. Respecto a la falta de documentación no me preocupa mucho, por el momento, solo es para un proyecto personal.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes tres opciones:

**1.- Usar reflection**, como lo propone @Alfabravo en [su respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/420752/54039)

**2.- Asignar valor por defecto a los parámetros**

```
public function miFunction($param1 = '')  {
    if($param1 == '') {
        // Aquí haces lo necesario cuando no se proporcionó el parámetro
        // o tiene el valor por defecto
    } // Puedes usar else { ...más código... }
    // Código cuando hay un parámetro correcto
}
```

**3. Especificar la función sin argumentos** y obtenerlos con [func_get_args()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.func-get-args.php), pero creo que es una mala práctica y te obligará a generar mucho más código

```
public function miFuncion() {
    $params = func_get_args();
    // Saber si se pasaron argumentos
    if(count($params) > 0) {
        // Deberás analizar cada uno
        // $params[0] es el primer argumento
        // $params[1] es el segundo (si es que se proporcionó)
    }
}
```

**Entrando de lleno en tu pregunta:**

> ¿Cómo podría saber si tengo que pasarle los argumentos para los parámetros establecidos?

Si estás programando con un IDE que tenga capacidad de autocompletado y sugerencias, lo ideal es [documentar correctamente](https://docs.phpdoc.org/3.0/guide/references/phpdoc/basic-syntax.html) tus scripts:

```
/**
 * Aquí describes lo que hace la función: Devuelve verdadero en caso de éxito o falso en caso de error
 * @param string $param1       Aquí describes el uso del parámetro
 * @return bool
 */
public function miFunction($param1 = '')  {
    if($param1 == '') {
        // No hay parámetro o es inválido
        return false;
    }
    // Código cuando hay un parámetro correcto
    return true;
}
```

Cuando estés escribiendo la función, tu IDE mostrará sugerencias para completar, incluyendo cantidad de parámetros, cada uno con su tipo de dato.